# UINavigationController in UITabBarController has a gap between the bottom of the view and keyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` that has `UINavigationControllers` as it's tabs.

When the keyboard opens up, there is a strange gap between the bottom of the view and the keyboard. I checked all my constraints and they look fine.

I have a different ViewController that has a `UITextView` and doesn't show that gap between it.

Here is my code that adds the keyboard height to the very bottom constraint so that it scrolls correctly and nothing gets hidden:

```
func setupKeyboardObserver() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWasShown:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
    })
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` instead

Comment: @Moxy Tried this and the keyboard just goes on top of everything, hiding the `UITextField`.

Comment: Could you add the implementation?

Comment: @Moxy Which part of the implementation did you want to see?

Comment: The method that's called when `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` is observed

Comment: @Moxy The code is already in my post. It is "keyboardWasShown" and "keyboardWillHide". I just replaced `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` with `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`.